# Can't chown volume in OS X, operation not permitted?

Tags: macos, chown

I'm trying to chown a volume, but I get "Operation not Permitted" no matter what permissions I change. I'm using OS X Leopard.

```
users-mac-pro:~ users$ chown 0:0 /Volumes/Snowfx
chown: /Volumes/Snowfx: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: And *why* would you want to do that? What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to test the permissions of this volume. I have full read/write permissions and it's not locked, but chown still won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to prefix the command with `sudo`.

However I don't see a practical reason for doing what you want. In most cases you want to leave volume's permissions or even ownership alone. As always, be careful with what you do when using `sudo`.